# Jave ee: "Update JPA Project" disable

Tags: java, eclipse, jpa, jakarta-ee, eclipse-neon

i'm running a big java ee project in eclipse neon and using jpa. Each time I change some of my content, "Update JPA project" is running in the background and consums all of my memory. 
I tried all of the following post but it didn't work:
[How do I stop JPA Facet on Eclipse from updating all the time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7359800/how-do-i-stop-jpa-facet-on-eclipse-from-updating-all-the-time)

Has anyone an idea how to solve this?